# How to add the "contextual menu command" in Excel addin

Tags: office-js

The [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-UX-Design-Patterns/blob/master/Helpful%20Templates/AddIn_Template_Excel_Desktop_reference.pdf) shows the "contextual menu command" example. I've searched it for but couldn't find any. It would be great to know its sample code. Also, a list of platforms support this. Thanks.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-UX-Design-Patterns/blob/master/Helpful%20Templates/AddIn_Template_Excel_Desktop_reference.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the sample you're looking for: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/blob/master/Excel/Manifest/ExcelAddinWithCommandsOnDataTab.xml. It shows how to let your add-in use a contextual command (which appears on the right-click menu in the Desktop version of Office).

The relevant xml element is `<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">`

-Michael Saunders, PM for Office add-ins